# Routing in React

Tags: reactjs, browser, react-router

So this is my router config

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/HITW" component={HITW} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

while using my app I am able to navigate to `http://localhost:62265/HITW` on click of the link, but when I am pasting this URL in browser it gives me an error `404 page not found`.

Is there a way to route URLs to component directly fired from the browser?

Comment: You must make sure your server is serving the `index.html` file for every route. Are you using the webpack dev server? Try setting [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) to `true`.

Comment: @Tholle I am using `webpack` with `browsersync` for development. I have hosted the app on windows `IIS`, so for production should I add all routes there